# Admin panel for Parse database

Tags: ruby-on-rails, parse-platform

We are building an application with backend on Parse.com. Parse provide data-browser on their site but support people/staff can't use due to complex interface and other point we can't share parse account due to security. We want to build admin panel using rails. Rails provides following nice gems for building admin panel with less code but none of these appear to support Parse.

```
-https://github.com/sferik/rails_admin  
-https://github.com/leikind/wice_grid  
-https://github.com/gregbell/active_admin
```

Can anyone share his experience building admin panel for Parse database?
Is there any gem available for making admin panel easir?

Thanks,
Junaid

Comment: You will need to query all your classes and replicate the response data in the table structure you want.

Comment: Deepesh : Are you talking about in context of Active_admin gem? If Yes then kindly explain more how this setup will work.

Comment: I had worked on similar concept, I wrote a JavaScript that in which i queried all my classes such that it returned all my parse data and then added same to my html page.

Comment: It seems to me that after following this approach, i will also have to do code to support CRUD opetations. ActiveAdmin provide lot of features , you may check demo here http://demo.activeadmin.info/admin

Answer (score 0):

You will need to write a JavaScript in which you will have to query all classes such that it returns all your parse data and then you will need to add same to your html page.